# python Automatic Resampling of Data

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

Let's say that I have the following data (measurements):

[image]

As you can see, there are a lot of sharp points (i.e. where the slope changes a lot). It would therefore, be good to take some more measurements around those points. To do that I wrote a script:

1. I calculate the curvature of 3 consecutive points: 
   Menger curvature: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menger_curvature#Definition
2. Then I decide which values I should resample, based on the curvature.

...and I iterate until the average curvature goes down... but it does not work, because, it goes up. Do you know why ?

Here is the complete code (stopped it after the length of the x values get 60):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def curvature(A,B,C):
    """Calculates the Menger curvature fro three Points, given as numpy arrays.
    Sources:
    Menger curvature: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menger_curvature#Definition
    Area of a triangle given 3 points: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/516219/finding-out-the-area-of-a-triangle-if-the-coordinates-of-the-three-vertices-are
    """

    # Pre-check: Making sure that the input points are all numpy arrays
    if any(x is not np.ndarray for x in [type(A),type(B),type(C)]):
        print("The input points need to be a numpy array, currently it is a ", type(A))

    # Augment Columns
    A_aug = np.append(A,1)
    B_aug = np.append(B,1)
    C_aug = np.append(C,1)

    # Caclulate Area of Triangle
    matrix = np.column_stack((A_aug,B_aug,C_aug))
    area = 1/2*np.linalg.det(matrix)

    # Special case: Two or more points are equal 
    if np.all(A == B) or  np.all(B == C):
        curvature = 0
    else:
        curvature = 4*area/(np.linalg.norm(A-B)*np.linalg.norm(B-C)*np.linalg.norm(C-A))

    # Return Menger curvature
    return curvature


def values_to_calulate(x,curvature_list, max_curvature):
    """Calculates the new x values which need to be calculated
    Middle point between the three points that were used to calculate the curvature """
    i = 0
    new_x = np.empty(0)
    for curvature in curvature_list:
        if curvature > max_curvature:
            new_x = np.append(new_x, x[i]+(x[i+2]-x[i])/3 )
        i = i+1
    return new_x


def plot(x,y, title, xLabel, yLabel):
    """Just to visualize"""

    # Plot
    plt.scatter(x,y)
    plt.plot(x, y, '-o')

    # Give a title for the sine wave plot
    plt.title(title)

    # Give x axis label for the sine wave plot
    plt.xlabel(xLabel)

    # Give y axis label for the sine wave plot
    plt.ylabel(yLabel)
    plt.grid(True, which='both')
    plt.axhline(y=0, color='k')


    # Display the sine wave
    plt.show
    plt.pause(0.05)

### STARTS HERE


# Get x values of the sine wave
x = np.arange(0, 10, 1);

# Amplitude of the sine wave is sine of a variable like time
def function(x):
    return 1+np.sin(x)*np.cos(x)**2
y = function(x)

# Plot it
plot(x,y, title='Data', xLabel='Time', yLabel='Amplitude')


continue_Loop = True

while continue_Loop == True :
    curvature_list = np.empty(0)
    for i in range(len(x)-2):
        # Get the three points
        A = np.array([x[i],y[i]])
        B = np.array([x[i+1],y[i+1]])
        C = np.array([x[i+2],y[i+2]])

        # Calculate the curvature
        curvature_value = abs(curvature(A,B,C))
        curvature_list = np.append(curvature_list, curvature_value)



    print("len: ", len(x) )
    print("average curvature: ", np.average(curvature_list))

    # Calculate the points that need to be added 
    x_new = values_to_calulate(x,curvature_list, max_curvature=0.3)

    # Add those values to the current x list:
    x = np.sort(np.append(x, x_new))

    # STOPED IT AFTER len(x) == 60
    if len(x) >= 60:
        continue_Loop = False

    # Amplitude of the sine wave is sine of a variable like time
    y = function(x)

    # Plot it
    plot(x,y, title='Data', xLabel='Time', yLabel='Amplitude')
```

This is how it should look:

[image]

EDIT:

If you let it run even further... :

[image]

Comment: Why did you stop at 60?

Comment: @VinceW. That's just random, I just didn't want to have to abort because the loop would just run infinitely.

Comment: What happens if you stop at 1000

Comment: And why should it go down in the first place?

Comment: @Julien The curvature of a straight line is 0. Hence, since, my curvature is calculated by 3 adjacent points, those points will get closer and closer, as more points are added to the plot. If the points get closer, they will more and more tend to be on an imaginary small straight line... Does this make sens ?

Comment: @VinceW. Please see my edit

Comment: If the curve is curved, it's curved, the curvature has no reason to go to zero. I think you are confusing yourself here, what you want is the absolute derivative change between two points, not the second derivative, i.e. d(df/dx), not d2f/dx2.

Comment: @Julien Hmm, I am not sure, that I completely understand you point. How is d(df/dx) different from d2f/dx2 ?

Comment: Will take a look in a little bit if still unanswered. Wondering if you are normalizing the area incorrectly

Comment: d(df/dx) = df/dx[n] - df/dx[n-1], d2f/dx2 = d(df/dx) / dx = (df/dx[n] - df/dx[n-1]) / (x[n] - x[n-1]), the first will go to 0, the second to the curve's curvature.

Comment: Ah my bad you are not using this definition of curvature. But may be this approach will be easier / faster to implement?

Comment: @Julien Thank you for your comment. Yes, maybe... if I have the time, I might try it. For now, I used this definition of the curvature: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menger_curvature#Definition

Comment: Have you checked that your curvature computation is correct on some simple examples?

Comment: @VinceW. Okay, thanks a lot ! Regarding the normalization, I tried to follow the Menger curvature definition as given by Wikipedia.

Comment: @Julien I tried it for a straight line, and I got 0, as expected, but other than that I have not checked it. Good point. Where could I get some references ?

Comment: So I checked your computation looks correct on some simple examples, but my original point stands: you are computing the average curvature of your curve which has no reason to go down. At every point, no matter how close your points get, the circle radius will  converge to what ever the curvature is at that point, not 0.

Comment: @Julien You are right ! Try the following: Take points on a perfect circle. A set which is far away from each other and a set which is close. It should give the same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So summarize my comments above:

- you are computing the average curvature of your curve which has no reason to go to 0. At every point, no matter how close your points get, the circle radius will converge to whatever the curvature is at that point, not 0.
- an alternative would be to use the absolute derivative change between two points: keep sampling until `abs(d(df/dx)) < some_threshold` where `d(df/dx) = (df/dx)[n] - (df/dx)[n-1]`